# Excel - Count rows whose values satisfy a complex condition without helper column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have 4 columns A, B, C and D, where each column has 100 rows of random integers (say between 1 and 10).

I want to be able to count the number of rows that satisfies a certain complex formula condition, for example

> (B / A > D / C) && (B > D)

I know I *could* add another (helper) column E to hold the value of the condition for each row, and then do a COUNTIF on that column, but I really want to avoid doing that if possible, as I have many many groups of 4 columns across my spreadsheet that I would have to add additional columns to. I know I can also hide this additional column, but I really just want to avoid this overhead if possible.

I can't seem to find any Excel reference where `COUNT` or `SUM` formulas allow the user to enter a formula-based-condition to include/exclude the row in the count total.

Is there a way of counting the matching rows directly on the existing data in the 4 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array formula.  For example:

```
 =SUM(IF(A1:A17/B1:B17>C1:C17/D1:D17,1,0))
```

will could all rows where A/B is > C/D.

Enter the formula using Ctrl+Shift+Enter - it should appear in the formula bar as:

```
{=SUM(IF(A1:A17/B1:B17>C1:C17/D1:D17,1,0))}
```

(Excel will add the braces for you)

Comment: Thanks Tim - while this part works for me, I'm having trouble adding in the second part of the condition. I'm trying something like... `=SUM(IF(AND(A1:A17/B1:B17>C1:C17/D1:D17, A1:A17>C1:C17),1,0))` but it doesn't give me the correct results (too few). Without the second part my results are as expected for the entered formula (but not what I need as I require the second part). Is using AND here in the IF formula the correct thing to do? Seems logical for me to do so. I'll play a little more. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again Tim - I have found my solution with the help of Robin below. Thank you for pointing out Array Formulas to me - a new dark magic which will prove useful in future I am sure.

Answer (score 2):

Extending Tim's answer -

In order to implement an `AND` condition in an array formula, you can use a nested `IF` statement.

If you think about an `AND` statement:

> X AND Y

Will evaluate to `TRUE` if both X and Y are true. Therefore, this pseudo-formula is equivalent to an `AND`:

> IF(X,IF(Y,1,0),0)

Which allows you to use this formula:

```
=SUM(IF(B2:B11/A2:A11>D2:D11/C2:C11,IF(B2:B11>D2:D11,1,0),0))
```

To implement the logic in your question i.e.

> (B / A > D / C) && (B > D)

Similarly to Tim's answer, you need to enter this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the desired outcome.

Sample:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Robin for your explanation - from it I discovered you can't use `AND` inside an `IF` in Array Formulas. However I took a slightly different approach to yours above and went with `=SUM(IF((A1:A17/B1:B17>C1:C17/D1:D17) * (A1:A17>C1:C17),1,0))` which gave me what I was after. Thanks for the pointers, and thanks for the edit - I wish i could accept your answer too as it compliments Tim's perfectly.